# How to get full path directory from JFileChooser into a string Java

Tags: java, string, swing, path, jfilechooser

so im trying to get my programme to chose a directory whit JFileChooser and then use the path to creat a text file using file writer and i cant get the JFileChooser part right :( pls help .

```
     public class parcourire0test {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub           

       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

         if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
          System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " + chooser.getSelectedFile());
```

//this is wher things dont work

```
          String Stringpath=Stringvalueof(chooser.getSelectedFile());
          System.out.println("Stringpath: " + Stringpath);


        } else {
          System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }


        }

         private static String Stringvalueof(File fi) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
         }

         }
```

but i get Stringpath : null

Comment: Start by taking a look at the [JavaDocs for `File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html). You'll be interested in either `getAbsolutePath` or `getCanonicalPath` depending on your needs

Comment: *"and then use the path to creat a text file using file writer"* - then make use of the support for `File`. `File` has a nice [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/File.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,java.lang.String)) for this purpose, `File(File, String)`, so you don't even need to care about converting the `File` reference to a `String` :/

Comment: thank yu very much for the quick response i ll try that and and see if i get it right this time  (^.^)